# Coordinate system to be used with qgis2web (QGIS to Leaflet)

Tags: qgis-3, leaflet, coordinates, wgs84, qgis2web

For my project in University I want to create an interactive map. My Prof told me, Leaflet only uses WGS84, but he wasn't sure. When using the qgis2web plugin, should I have WGS84 as project coordinate system or is any other system also fine? If no, which WGS84 coordinate system should I use (e.g. EPSG:4326; EPSG:4979).

Comment: See DefinedCRSs section in https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#projection

Answer (score 6):

`qgis2web` leverages [`proj4leaflet`](http://kartena.github.io/Proj4Leaflet/) under the hood, so you should be able to use any CRS supported by [`proj4js`](http://proj4js.org/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the CRS you want by setting it in QGIS at the bottom right.
When you export the map with qgis2web you have to select "Match Project CRS" in the "Appearance" tab like this:

[image]

A string will be added to the index.html file that adds that specific CRS to the project. In this case I set 3857, the index is written like this:

```
var crs = new L.Proj.CRS('EPSG:3857', '+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +k=1 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +no_defs', {
            resolutions: [2800, 1400, 700, 350, 175, 84, 42, 21, 11.2, 5.6, 2.8, 1.4, 0.7, 0.35, 0.14, 0.07],
        });
```

Answer (score -2):

When using the qgis2web plugin to create an interactive map, you should use the WGS84 coordinate system as the project coordinate system. WGS84 (World Geodetic System 1984) is the most widely used geographic coordinate system, and is the default coordinate system used by the qgis2web plugin.

The WGS84 coordinate system is based on the WGS84 ellipsoid, which is a model of the Earth's shape. It is used as the reference system for latitude and longitude coordinates, and is the standard coordinate system for GPS (Global Positioning System) applications.

In terms of specific EPSG codes, you can use EPSG:4326 or EPSG:4979 as the WGS84 coordinate system for your project. Both of these EPSG codes use the WGS84 ellipsoid and the same units (decimal degrees), but they differ in the way that they handle the Prime Meridian and the International Date Line. EPSG:4326 uses the Greenwich Prime Meridian and the International Date Line, while EPSG:4979 uses the Paris Prime Meridian and the 180th meridian.

In general, it is best to use EPSG:4326 as the WGS84 coordinate system for your project, as this is the most widely used and recognized WGS84 coordinate system. However, if you have specific requirements or preferences, you can use EPSG:4979 instead.

Comment: I'm afraid there is an error in your answer, where it says: _"EPSG:4979 uses the Paris Prime Meridian and the 180th meridian"_. What is the source of that information?